# Поиск значение обьекта в массиве

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть массив с обьектами

```
data = [{service_id: 7777}, {service_id:9999}]
```

у меня есть допустим переменная с айди

```
var myid = 9999
```

как мне проверить существование этого ади в массиве ?

средствами angularjs или javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Вот пример:***

```js
var data = [{service_id: 7777}, {service_id:9999}]
function getServicebyId(id) 
{
  return data.filter(
 function(data)
     { return data.service_id== id});
}
var myid = 9999
var found = getServicebyId(myid);
alert(found)
```

Comment: Фильтр проходится по всему массиву. А если они размером с 100000 штук?

Comment: @Other, все еще будет не заметно

Comment: @Grundy, незаметно для глаза, а если в качестве одно из сотни гаек приложения per sec.?

Comment: @Other, не понял сообщение после _незаметно для глаза_

Comment: @Grundy, если помимо поиска объекта будет ещё сотня операций и так каждую секунду (или каждые 16.6ms).

Comment: @Other, то будет уже совсем другой вопрос :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ТЗ не освещалось, решаю как хочу :)

Comment: спасибо. вроде бы помогло. еще подскажите как сделать проверку. что бы было условие if else

Comment: @Other, у `[].some` тоже O(n), что если искомый объект будет последним?

Comment: @vp_arth, а если первым?

Comment: В среднем - это неважно.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
let data = [{service_id: 7777}, {service_id:9999}],
    id   = 7777;

let isFound = data.some(_ => _.service_id === id);

console.info(isFound);
```

Comment: В IE и Edge это не сработает.

Comment: @koks_rs, для отсталых браузеров есть полифиллы.

Comment: @koks_rs, в EDGE сработает

Comment: Полифилов для  `arrow functions` быть не может. Транспайлер.

Comment: @vp_arth, значит поменять на обычную функцию. Или, что лучше, использовать `Babel` и забыть о кошмарах от мелкософта.

Comment: Меня больше смущает использование подошвы. Нафиг эту обфускацию)

Comment: Вы про видимый пробел? Лень писать больше букв, если видимость ограничивается пятью символами :)

Comment: @Grundy, да и правда, в EDGE работает.

Answer (score 1):

2)

```js
var data = [
    {
        "service_id": 7777,
        "service_id": "9999"
    }
];

function getServicebyId(service_id) {
    var found = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var element = data[i];

        if (element.service_id == service_id) {
           found = element;
       } 
    }

    return found;
}

console.info(getServicebyId(9999));
```

Answer (score 1):

решил так

```
$scope.manageFavorService = function (serviceId) {
         var data = {};//sending an empty array to get response
         getService = serviceId;

         PortalApi.getFavorServices(data)//get an array with all favorites services
         .then(function(data) {
             function getFavorList(id)//looking if there already serviceId exist
             {
                 return data.filter(function(data)
                     { return data.service_id== id});
             }

             $scope.isFavorite = getFavorList(getService),
                 data = {serviceId:serviceId};

             if ($scope.isFavorite.length == 0) {//add favorite if in answer we got empty array
                 ******
             }
             else {//del favorite if in answer we got array with our service

             }
         });
     };
```

Answer (score -1):

**Прмер с условие if else**

```js
var data = [{service_id: 7777}, {service_id:9999}]
function getServicebyId(id) 
{
  return data.filter(
 function(data)
     { return data.service_id== id});
}
function isEmpty(value) {
    if (!value) {
      return true;
    }    
    for (var key in value) {
      if (hasOwnProperty.call(value, key)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
var myid = 19999
var found = getServicebyId(myid);
alert(found);
if (!isEmpty(found)) alert("Yes"); else alert("No");
```